# UIStepper Xcode Interface Builder alignment issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel, uistepper

I'm not sure why but when I try to align my UIStepper in IB in line with my label, it is not inline when I run it. So I have to adjust my UIStepper a lot lower than my labels in order to get it alined. Please see the picture:

Does anyone know why?[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your **Autoresizing** positions for the `UIStepper` are set correctly, the example in the screenshot should align your `UIStepper` with the `UILabel`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. Initially the autosizing was just like your screenshot but it was not showing when I was running it but played around with it and now staying where it's suppose to :)

Comment: Changed the **Autosizing** to **Top & Left** ,, fixed the problem , thanks